# New Irish passport (dual citizen) can I use it to avoid longer non EU passport control lines?

Tags: schengen, customs-and-immigration, eu-citizens

I just got my Irish passport today (I have my U.S. passport too). When I have gone through airports in Europe (just recently to Italy) I had gotten a connecting flight in Paris.

By the time I had gotten through the 200+ people line waiting for passport control, I missed my next flight. The EU line had no people and the few went right through.

So I would like to know for instance when I do a trip like that again, once I get to a European airport can I just go through the Schengen country line instead of standing in the non-EU line passport control?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, why not? Incidentally, you're also allowed to use the "all passports" line even if you would not usually want to do that (technically, it's not a non-EU passport but really an "all passports" line). The control should also be quicker/simpler: no stamps, no questions, possibly scanning your passport but that's about it usually.

Comment: Thank you! That is wonderful news. I have missed flights twice due to that problem. I will use it on my next trip.

Comment: As an Irish citizen, you're an EU citizen, you can also pass the control without having to answer any question and then decide you want to live in France and get a job without having to apply for any visa or permit. That's what the freedom of movement is all about!

Comment: I have another question if anyone can give a suggestion. I have been to Russia years ago but I just had my US passport. I didn't have any issues getting a visa but I would like to go back (my best friend lives there). Would it be okay to use the Irish passport for a visa for my next trip there or should I just use my US passport?

Comment: @Margaret: When traveling to a third country (such as Russia) which treats neither US nor Irish citizens specially, you would need a visa in either case. Since you have been there before using your US passport, it might be easier or faster to get another visa using the same passport. But it probably doesn't matter either way.

Comment: Hello Margaret, you should read up on your rights as an EU citizen in other EU countries, and those of your family members. You probably won't run for municipal elections in another country soon, but you can ... http://ec.europa.eu/justice/citizen/

Comment: Excellent link, thank you very much! I am definitely going to look at the site you mentioned.

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely. As an Irish citizen, you may use the EU Citizen queue (and you should, since you are an Irish citizen).

For detailed information about which passport to use where, see the question [I have two passports/nationalities. How do I use them when I travel?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel) Since both the US and Ireland have no problem with holding two citizenships, your situation is straightforward and fairly common.

Comment: Thank you! I am so happy to hear that. When I had read all these other posts about needing entry/exit stamps in different passports I was confused but I will definitely do this next trip!

Comment: @Margaret people get all paranoid about entry and exit stamps but it's mostly in their heads. In particular, most countries don't look for an entering traveler to have an exit stamp from the country they just left. At any rate, as an EU and US citizen, you don't need to worry about this in the least when you are in the EU or the US.

Comment: @Margaret Also, if you're married, you can take your spouse and certain other family members to the EU line even if the family member has only a non-EU passport, because your freedom of movement right includes the right to move freely with your family members.

Comment: Thank you for both of those tips! I had seen so many posts about the stamps I was concerned but that clarifies it and I appreciate it! I had never given it a thought before until those postings. Thanks again!